# Firebase Authorization Weird State after 24 Hours

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

I understand that by default Firebase invalidates a login token after 24 hours.  However, I am finding the behavior strange after this time period.  When the app is run it checks to see if the user is logged in and if so it goes into the app otherwise it stays on the login screen:

```
if self.ref.authData != nil
{
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainTabSegue", sender: self)
}
```

This works fine unless the token has expired after 24 hours.  What will happen then is that the app will still see that authData is not nil and it will send it to the next VC.  The next VC makes uses of the UID which then causes the app to crash.  Running the app again will then show that authData is in fact nil and the user will be asked to login as is expected.

So the question is why, after the 24 hour period, is authData not nil  when the user is clearly not logged in?  The Firebase documentation seems to indicate that checking authData as above is the correct way to determine whether a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Before your segue if you extract the uid from authData then you can pass that user to the first view controller. If you pass the user object to your first VC constructed in the App Delegate, then your app won't crash. I vaguely remember something similar happening to my app (i.e. where it thinks the user is logged in but then changes back to login). I'm not sure why this happened but it's possible the app tried to start where it left off?

You can also change the token expiration length on Firebase, as you may know.